# Android Firebase query data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to query data from firebase database.Below images show data structure. [image].Im trying to query messages by data(long value is the time in milli seconds).Below is the code :

```
database.child("Market").child("data").child("messages").orderByKey().startAt("1473777076600").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            MessageFirebaseHelper data = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessageFirebaseHelper.class);

            Object[] messageKeys = data.getMessages().keySet().toArray();

            for(int i=0;i<messageKeys.length;i++){
                Logger.i(TAG, " messages  keys :  " + messageKeys[i]);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Below is the error:

```
W/ClassMapper(8838): No setter/field for 1473777892283 found on class com.app.MessageFirebaseHelper
```

As the keys change dynamically, creating getter/setter is not correct.
  How do i get the data and save it ?

TRY 2:

I tried in different way,  Query :

```
database.child("Market").child("data").orderByChild("time")
.startAt("1473777076600").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

This does not return any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,,

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

     for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            yourModel mModel = eventSnapshot.getValue(yourModel.class);
            Log.e("DATA" ,""+ mModel);   
     }

}
```