# How to retrieve all the data from Firebase and put it on a RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

here is my database structure[image]

I want to retrieve all the datas from the child `Passenger` and put it inside a `RecyclerView`...How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FirebaseUI for Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library.

Just add the dependency (the 0.5.3 works with firebase 9.4.0 libraries):

```
dependencies {
    // Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.3'
}
```

Define your `DatabaseReference`:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("passengers");
```

Then:

- Create a custom `ViewHolder` class
- Create a custom subclass `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`

The `ViewHolder` class:

```
public static class PassengerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

}
```

The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` class:

```
RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_recycler);
recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Passenger, PassengerHolder>(Passenger.class, R.layout.mylayout, PassengerHolder.class, mRef) {
    @Override
    public void populateViewHolder(PassengerHolder passengerViewHolder, Passenger passenger, int position) {
        passengerViewHolder.setName(passenger.getName());
        //.......

    }
};
recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: I also wanted to use `CardView` sir. How is it possible?

Comment: @tin In your layout file (referenced by R.layout.mylayout) just include a CardView.

Comment: Hi, @GabrieleMariotti I am having the same issue with my application. I can't seem to read all data instead my app only reads data from first node / user. Please can you help out, I tried what your doing here but my structure is a bit different and I can't seem to get it working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797009/using-search-view-android-with-firebase

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
     FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   //Your Logic here
                    for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    YourModel mModel = eventSnapshot.getValue(YourModel.class);
                    Log.e("DATA" ,""+ mModel);   
                  }  
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

You have to create an array list for your `Recycleview` and add each model i.e `mModel` to your arraylist and display in your list

[More Info 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476997/android-firebase-query-data/39477133#39477133)